# r2020a matlab_kernel not supporting python 3.8

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install 'matlab_kernel' for JupyterLab.
But I am getting stuck at step `python setup.py install` with an issue

> OSError: MATLAB Engine for Python supports Python version 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7, but your version of Python is 3.8

Following this video here: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WufMGW5Bv4g`
He installs it perfectly with the same version of MATLAB and python.
What am I missing ??
(I am successfully able to install octave_kernel)